# CSV importa los datos pero agrega una línea en blanco

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, csv, importación

Tengo este código PHP para importar archivos CSV a mi BBDD.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$allowed = array('csv');
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (!in_array($ext, $allowed)) {
    // show error message
    $message = 'Invalid file type, please use .CSV file!';
} else {

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "files/" . $_FILES['file']['name']);

    $file = "files/" . $_FILES['file']['name'];

    $query = <<<eof
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file'
     INTO TABLE usuarios
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
     IGNORE 1 LINES
    (acro_usuario,nombre,apellidos,departamento,email,empresa)
eof;
    if (!$result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
        exit(mysqli_error($con));
    }
    $message = "CSV file successfully imported!";
}
}
```

Pero el problema es que agrega una línea en blanco, si acceso a PhpMyAdmin elimino la línea en blanco y indica esto:

```
DELETE FROM `usuarios` WHERE `usuarios`.`acro_usuario` = ''
```

Si cambio a

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'

DELETE FROM `usuarios` WHERE `usuarios`.`acro_usuario` = '\n'
```

Si cambio a

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

No indica error.

Comment: No entiendo bien cual es el problema, ¿la linea en blanco? ¿No habrá en el CSV una linea final con datos vacíos?

Comment: Pero lo que me resulta raro, es que la pone en la primera línea y que yo sepa no, revisare ahora después.